# "react-router-dom " router component does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, react-router-dom, history

I want to use history explicitly. So I know about BrowserRoute but I want to use Route and use history as its property. when I run the program I get this page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lha0U.png)

This is my AppRouter.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import LoginPage from "../components/LoginPage";
import ExpenseDashboardPage from "../components/ExpenseDashboardPage";
import AddExpensePage from "../components/AddExpensePage";
import EditExpensePage from "../components/EditExpensePage";
import NotFoundPage from "../components/NotFoundPage";
import PublicRoute from "./PublicRoute";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

LoginPage.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { startLogin } from "../actions/auth";

export const LoginPage = ({ startLogin }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={startLogin}>Login with Google</button>
    <button>Amir Hossein Jobeiri</button>
  </div>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  startLogin: () => dispatch(startLogin()),
});

export default connect(undefined, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

PublicRoute.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const PublicRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    component={(props) =>
      isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <Component {...props} />
    }
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.uid,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute);
```

PrivateRoute

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/Header";

export const PrivateRoute = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    component={(props) =>
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Component {...props} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.uid,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

I searched a lot about this problem but I do not get the right answer. Please help if you can.

Comment: what is the version of the history package?

Comment: if add code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) is better for debugging.thanks.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you https://gist.github.com/rcanepa/b4ce0dff8d85b357504e04b03e69ac66

Answer (score 0):

I changed my "history" version to "4.7.2". It works properly.